# How to show FTP server list in ListBox using MFC

Tags: c++, ftp, mfc

I want to make an FTP server client using MFC.

Server connection has been successful.

How do I print a list of FTP server files and diretory in the list box??

Any advice would be appreciated with a simple example.

```
CInternetSession m_Session;
CFtpConnection* m_pConnection;
CFtpFileFind* m_pFileFind;
CListBox m_List;
CString m_strIP, m_strID, m_strPass;

void CMFC_FTPDlg::ConnectFTP()
{
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_IP, m_strIP);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_ID, m_strID);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_PASS, m_strPass);
    m_nPort = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT_PORT);
    
    m_pConnection = m_Session.GetFtpConnection(m_strIP, m_strID, m_strPass, m_nPort);
    
    if(!m_pConnection)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("ERROR : Disconnected!!");
        m_pConnection = NULL;
        m_bContinue = FALSE;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Connected!!");
        m_bContinue = TRUE;
    }
}

void CMFC_FTPDlg::ShowList()
{
    int nResult;
    nResult = m_pConnection->SetCurrentDirectory("test");
}
```

Comment: Q: How to I *GET* a list of FTP server files and directories?  A: You learn the FTP protocol, and use FTP commands: https://www.serv-u.com/ftp-server-windows/commands.  Or you get an FTP library that "wraps" the low level protocol for you.  Like the Microsoft [Cftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpconnection-class?view=msvc-160) classes.

Comment: @paulsm4 the code is using MFC's `CFtpConnection` class, which is "an FTP library that "wraps" the low level protocol for you".

Comment: `nResult = m_pFileFind->FindFile();

 while(nResult != 0)
 {
  nResult = m_pFileFind->FindNextFile();
 }`

Comment: As I said, I am searching for a file until there is no next file. What I am curious about is how to save the file name and show it in the listbox.

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation, [Steps in a Typical FTP Client Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/steps-in-a-typical-ftp-client-application), you need to use the [`CFtpFileFind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpfilefind-class) class, which has [`FindFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpfilefind-class#findfile) and [`FindNextFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpfilefind-class#findnextfile) methods for enumerating an FTP server's files.

You already have a `CFtpFileFind* m_pFileFind` variable declared, but you are not using it.

Try this:

```cpp
void CMFC_FTPDlg::ShowList()
{
    int nResult;
    nResult = m_pConnection->SetCurrentDirectory("test");

    CFtpFileFind finder(m_pConnection);
    BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(_T("*"));
    while (bWorking)
    {
        bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
        // use finder.GetFileURL() or finder.GetFileName() as needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said, I am searching for a file until there is no next file. What I am curious about is how to save the file name and show it in the listbox.

Comment: @SJW `finder` gives you the file name/path/url as a string. What is stopping you from adding that string to your Listbox? `CListBox` has an `AddString()` method.

Comment: @SJW `finder` gives you each file's name/path/url as a string. What is stopping you from adding that string to your Listbox? `CListBox` has an `AddString()` method.